# Contour and perimeter recognition in binary image

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing, image-recognition, pattern-recognition

I need to detect contour (object) and find the perimeter of a detected object.

For example, I have the following image:

[image]

All images are binary, so they consist of only `0` and `1`.

I need to firstly detect objects, and then find the perimeter of the object contour, the area will be known I guess because this is just the sum of all object pixels.

I am using 4-pixel coherence while finding objects.

I have found some algorithms, but cannot figure out how they work and how to implement them if I have an array of 1 and 0.

Please, can someone provide explanation or code example of the easiest to understand the algorithm.

I need to do this without using `OpenCV` or any other library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

1. Small opening in order to erase all the small patterns.
2. Connected component labeling in order to detect, label and separate your objects. [See here for java codes](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d480842/general-developpement/algorithme-mathematiques/contribuez/java-etiquettage-composantes-connexes-union-find/).
3. Perimeter extraction (each non null pixel with at least one black neighbor).